# How do I add 'active' class dynamically in loop on the laravel blade? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

My view is like this :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
    @foreach($countries as $country)
        <li role="presentation"><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab" @click="$refs.player.getPlayer({{ $country->id }})">{{ ucfirst($country->name) }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

I want add `class="active"` in li tag. So, when the tab clicked, the li tag will active. And I want first loop will active too

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will follow instructions about [The Loop Variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable) you will find usefull **$loop->first** helper. It returns true if it's first item in an array.  So you can do this:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <li class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">...</li>
@endforeach
```

Then on tab class click if you want to move class to active tab you should make it by using javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to do this also!

1. Set an ID to your li tag.
2. Get your li tag element by the id.
3. `.addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0):

I have used a laravel package in the past if you need a quick fix

https://github.com/dwightwatson/active

Answer (score 0):

Just Use $loop->first active in your li class.
`class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"`

Sample example:-

```
@foreach ($category as $v_cat)
<li class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="#{{$v_cat->category_name}}" data-toggle="tab">{{$v_cat->category_name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```